# Solr dismax highlighting not respecting analyzer

Tags: java, solr, search-engine, edismax, dismax

In the schema of *Solr 3.6.2* there are two `field` declarations, `text` and `exact`

```
<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
<field name="exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

The former using `StandardTokenizer` and the latter `KeywordTokenizer`.

Solr queries describing the problem:

```
?hl=true
&hl.fl=text,exact
&defType=edismax
&qf=text+exact         <-------- here
&q=a-b
```

**Highlight output for field *exact***:
`<em>a</em>-<em>b</em>`.
The problem is the summary for field `exact` is produced using the analyzer from `text`.

```
?hl=true
&hl.fl=text,exact
&defType=edismax
&qf=exact              <-------- here
&q=a-b
```

**Highlight output for field *exact***:
`<em>a-b</em>`. 
By simply removing `text` from `qf` we get the correct analyzer, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `debugQuery` on

```
+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((exact:a-b) | ((text:a text:b)~2)))
```

Solr highlighter after finding a match in `exact` also seem to match `a` and `b` only based on the presence in the query. [`hl.requireFieldMatch=true`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.requireFieldMatch) does seem to combat that!